# Keyboard shortcut to insert « (guillemets ) in Xtend templates?

Tags: xtend

The [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#templates) says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd><</kbd> but is seems not to work (I have Mmac with a US Keyboard). I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to insert a pair of quotes.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd><</kbd> is the short-cut to «»

Answer (score 2):

Simply use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> (Show proposals) on any *Mac* within an *Xtend* `'''Rich String'''`, Eclipse will automatically insert `«»` in your rich string: `'''Rich String «»'''`